# Passing struct to function call doesn't work

Tags: c, function, struct

Since C does not support pass by reference, and I'm developing something that cannot use heap memory, how can I make this work? I want the function call set_var_name to actually change the variables global_log instead of just a local copy. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Record 
{ 
    char type[1];
    char var_name[1014];
    void* var_address;
    char is_out_dated[1];
}; 

struct Global_Log
{
    struct Record records[1024];
    int next_slot;
};

void set_var_name(struct Global_Log global_log, int next_slot, char* data, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        global_log.records[0].var_name[i] = data[i];
    printf("%s\n",global_log.records[0].var_name);//here prints out "hello"
}

int main()
{
    struct Global_Log global_log;
    char a[6] = "hello";
    set_var_name(global_log, 0, a, 6);
    printf("%s\n",global_log.records[0].var_name); // here prints out nothing
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All function parameters in C are passed by value. So the `set_var_name` is operating on a **local copy** of the variables.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized it as well. Is there any way I can make this work without using pointer?

Comment: Pointer is the best way. A not so good way is to return the structure - that isn't good as it is inefficient to pass copies of large structs around. A very bad way is to use a global variable.

Comment: @kaylum what about passing an array to a function? I assume it is passed by reference.

Comment: Pointer is the best way. Either `struct foo *p` or `const struct foo *p` and `p->bar`. I have _never_ used `struct foo v` and `v.bar` when `v` is an arg. All uses I've seen [in real code] were problematic and had to be replaced with a pointer [which was _way_ faster]. A [c++ style] reference is implemented as a [hidden] _pointer_, so `struct mystruct &r` and doing `r.bar` is mere syntactic sugar and generates the equivalent code to `p->bar`. So, references _hide_ the fact that _some_ pointer deref is done. So, references are _not_ faster than pointers. Just get comfy with `p->bar`

Comment: And, with the real code example I mentioned, the struct was fairly large and having `struct foo myfnc(struct foo arg) { ... return arg; }` was so slow that the code could _not_ meet the timing requirements and [once again] _had_ to be replaced.

Comment: **ALL** parameters are passed by value in C. No exceptions. It's a common beginner misunderstanding regarding arrays. When an array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer. That is, the pointer is passed by value. You can't change the pointer value and have it reflect back to the caller. What you can do is change what the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are working with a copy of the struct instance, instead of a reference. Try passing a pointer of a struct as a parameter, so you can work with a reference of the instance:

```
void set_var_name(struct Global_Log* global_log, int next_slot, char* data, int size)
```

Another alternative is using a global variable, since it sounds like there won't be another instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

C is a call-by-value language -- when you call a function, all arguments are passed by value (that is, a copy is made into the callee's scope) and not by reference.  So any changes to the arguments in the function only affect the copy in the called function.

If you want to call "by reference", you need to do it explicitly by passing a pointer and dereferencing it in the called function.